# Deleting/Updating nested object using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am relatively new to react-native programming language. I've been trying to make my first standalone application, which of course is To Do List app.
I have to do items under their own respective categories. The source of these to do items is a predefined object as shown below.

```
const [listData, setListData] = useState([
{
  id: 1,
  title: "Work",
  data: [
    {
      text: 'MSD',
      key: 1
    },
    {
      text: 'Cosmo',
      key: 2
    },
    {
      text: 'Jackson',
      key: 3
    },
  ]
},
{
  id: 2,
  title: "Home",
  data: [
    {
      text: 'Gym',
      key: 4
    },
    {
      text: 'Dinner',
      key: 5
    },
    {
      text: 'React',
      key: 6
    },
  ]
},
  ]);
```

This data is defined inside the main function App(). The data renders perfectly on screen with the below code.
[Home Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3sKB.png)

```
return(
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Header />
  <SectionList
    sections={listData}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
    renderSectionHeader={({ 
      section: { title } }) => (
        <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
    )}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Item data={item.text} dataID={item.key} onDeleteHandler={onDeleteHandler}/>}
  />
</View>
  )
```

Item component code is -

```
const Item = ({ data, dataID, onDeleteHandler }) => {

const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

return(
<View style={styles.itemGroup}>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => {
    if (checked == true){ 
      setChecked(false)
    }
    else{
      setChecked(true)
    }
  }}>
    <View>
      <Text style={checked === true ? styles.toDoTextStrikeThrough : styles.toDoText}>{data}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onDeleteHandler(dataID)}>
    <View style={styles.checkBoxAndDeleteStyle}>
      <Entypo name="cross" color='#004d4d' size={18}/>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
)
};

export default Item;
```

The bit where i'm stuck at is the delete button which invokes the below function.

```
  const onDeleteHandler = (key) => {

const parentArray = [...listData]

  for (let i = 0; i < parentArray.length; i++)
  {
    let paDataItems = {...parentArray[i]}.data
    const dataArray = [...paDataItems]
    for (let k = 0; k < dataArray.length; k++){
      if (dataArray[k].key === key){
        dataArray.splice(k,1)
        break
      }
    }
    console.log(dataArray)
  }
  }
```

dataArray shows all the correct objects. I am not able to figure out how to update this back to the main dataset. 
I've tried the below two methods and both result in weird behaviours.

```
    setListData((paDataItems) => [...paDataItems,{data:dataArray}])

    setListData([{...parentArray[i]}, {data:dataArray}])
```

How should I write this function so I can delete the selected item?
I'm guessing I should be able to figure out how to update the dataset once I have a solution to the above problem.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the groups/categories and filter the data array:

```
const onDeleteHandler = key => {
  const newData = listData.map(category => ({
      ...category,
      data: category.data.filter(item => item.key !== key)
    })
  );
  setListData(newData);
};
```

It may be more correct to use a functional state update since the next state depends on the previous state having an task item deleted correctly in the case that multiple state updates are queued up within a single render cycle:

```
const onDeleteHandler = key => {
  setListData(listData => listData.map(category => ({
      ...category,
      data: category.data.filter(item => item.key !== key)
    })
  ));
};
```

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Work",
    data: [{
        text: 'MSD',
        key: 1
      },
      {
        text: 'Cosmo',
        key: 2
      },
      {
        text: 'Jackson',
        key: 3
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Home",
    data: [{
        text: 'Gym',
        key: 4
      },
      {
        text: 'Dinner',
        key: 5
      },
      {
        text: 'React',
        key: 6
      },
    ]
  },
];

const onDeleteHandler = key => {
  const newData = data.map(category => ({
      ...category,
      data: category.data.filter(item => item.key !== key)
    })
  );
  return newData;
};

console.log(onDeleteHandler(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your `onDeleteHandler` function like this:

```
const newData = listData.map(group => {
    return { 
        ...group,
        data: group.data.filter(task => task.key !== key)
    }
})
setListData(newData);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Just that the setListData(newData) was unreachable in your snippet. I had to move it all the way out of the code for newData.